# Weird style behavior when (not) using ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I need to display a checkbox list into a bootstrap modal. I was using angular ng-repeat to display the various checkboxes and it was working fine:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="l in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{ l }}" /> {{ l }}
</label>
```

[image: Result using ng-repeat]

Then the only thing I changed was manually creating all the checkboxes:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="A" /> A
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="B" /> B
</label>
....
```

And there is a little space after the letters which break the style.
[image: Result adding the checkboxes manually]

That may be a stupid thing but I really don't see where this change in the style comes from! Does someone has an idea why there is that extra space when not using ng-repeat ?

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4hkw8h43/
First button open the modal without ng-repeat and the second with ng-repeat...

Comment: After more tests, it is not directly coming from ng-repeat but from dynamically added elements: https://jsfiddle.net/4hkw8h43/11/. The 4th modal has ABCD coming from HTML and EFGH dynamically added with javascript. We can see there is no space after E or F, but there is one after C or D. How to explain this ?

Answer (score 2):

As you have already found out, this is a white-space issue that often occurs when using `display: inline-block;` to align stuff horizontally. I cannot tell you why it happens in this case, but how to fix it. This fix will be useful for you in the future.

To fix it, implement the following:

```
.whitespace-eliminator {
    font-size: 0;
}
.whitespace-eliminator label {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4hkw8h43/2/

So basically, setting `font-size: 0;` on the parent makes the white-space vanish visually. Afterwards you have to reset font-size of child elements that still have `font-size: inherit;` internally otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, I will use this fix. But I'd still like to understand what happens when using / not using ng-repeat. I see absolutely no difference in the elements and their style so why don't they appear the same...